# How to configure a cron job to run every 30 mins in the week, and saturday and sunday only every 2 hours?

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have configured a cronjob to run every half an hour from 6am to 8pm.

`*/30 6-20 * * *`

But now I need to a exception for saturday and sunday to run every 2 hours from 6am to 8pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jenkinsJob/configure -> Build Triggers -> Build periodically , add following cron in schedule

```
0 6-20/2 * * 6-7
*/30 6-20 * * 1-5
```

- We can add multiple crons
- At every minute, job is validated for all crons, if current dateTime satisfies any cron, job gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

With Jenkins you would just add two Cron Triggers.

```
*/30 6-20 * * 1-5
0 6-20/2 * * 6-7
```

This allows clear definitions for when things should run and makes things easier to read.
You can check in the UI for when the CRON would have last run and when it should next run as well.